# Question about a set being compact

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function,and $K$ constant and put

$$ A = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) - K= 0 \} $$

Let $F = f - K$. We know $F$ is contiunous and hence $A = F^{-1}( \{ 0 \}) $ is closed since singletons are closed. What other condition do we need in $A$ in order for $A$  to be bounded, hence compact??

Comment: Is there any context to why you'd like to do this?

Comment: $F$ isn't required. $A=f^{-1}(\{K\})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $A$ to be bounded, then it is necessary and sufficient that there exists $c > 0$ such that $||x|| > c$ implies $|F(x)| > 0$. This follows immediately from the definition of boundedness for sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

As a previous post remarked, we could ask $\lim_{||x||\rightarrow\infty} |F(x)| = \infty$, but certainly the function need not be unbounded for $A$ to be bounded! We could ask the growth condition $\liminf_{||x||\rightarrow\infty} |F(x)| > 0$. This is sufficient but not necessary. For instance, if $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined to be $F(x)=x$ on $[-1,1]$ and $F(x)=e^{-(|x|-1)^2}$ everywhere else, then the $\liminf = \lim = 0$, while $A=\{0\}$ for this $F$. Outside of $[-1,1]$, the function I defined is just the Gaussian (bell curve).

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=F%28x%29%3De%5E%7B-%28%7Cx%7C-1%29%5E2%7D
(This graph shows the behavior outside $[-1,1]$.)

If there is any question about the definition this notion of $\liminf$, it is covered on Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Functions_from_metric_spaces_to_metric_spaces

Answer (score 0):

If $x = (x(1), x(2),\ldots, x(n))$ then we need that there is a $C > 0$ such that $|x(k)|<C$ for all $k = 1, 2,\ldots, n$. We can take this to be the condition to guarantee boundedness of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

A growth conditition on $f$ is sufficient, for example:
$$\lim_{||(x_1,\cdots,x_n)||\to\infty}|f(x)|=\infty.$$